# MySQL thinks Master & Slave have same server-id, but they don't

Tags: mysql, replication

Trying to setup MySQL to run one-way replication. I have the master set to server_id = 1, a replication user setup, binary logging enabled, the Slave server_id = 2 and is connected and waiting for an event. I am also using Workbench.

However, the Master server has the following error...

```
Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
```

I can't figure out any reason for this error. I have looked at dozens of tutorials, manuals, etc and none of them is explaining to me what is happening.

Comment: How have you set the server_id on each master/slave? If you changed the config file, did you restart mysql after this? What does `select @@global.server_id` on master an slave show?

Comment: possible duplicate https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/mysql-thinks-master-slave-have-the-same-server-id

Comment: I appreciate the notice Ahmad, but I have referenced that before and it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I set the server-id using the my.ini file and I have also enabled logging through the my.ini file by specifying the log-bin base value. I restarted the MySQL service after those modifications.

Comment: @danblack "select @@global.server_id" on master results in a 1. When ran on the slave it results in a 2.

Answer (score 0):

The server-id is stored in the /var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf in addition to the standard my.cnf config file.

When cloning the data directory from master to slave, you need to delete the auto.cnf file in the data directory (i.e. /var/lib/mysql) before starting the slave.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am doing this on windows and so our directories may be different but I only see auto.cnf in the directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data. The file also only has a couple of lines in it showing "[auto]" and the "server-uuid".

Comment: There is no risk in deleting the auto.cnf file.  Stop MySQL, delete the file, and Restart MySQL.  That may resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your master set to server_id = 1, and your Slave server_id = 2 and it isn´t work it, You need to change the service_id but directly on Workbench. So you need to go to Administration and select the option 'Options File', later in the tab 'General' serch the 'informational' check the server-id and change it if you are in the master set to server_id=1, if you are in the slave set to server_id=2 and finally aply the change. Reset the service MySQL and now try to do the connection master-slave again. I did it and my connection master-slave worked. I am Mexican so I know my redaction is not the best, but I hope you can understand me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

for those who using `docker` to test replication(2 container on same host), don't use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` when issuing `CHANGE MASTER`, it's container's address not host's, so MySQL is complaining this error even `server_id` is different on those 2 instances.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/1347716) to see how to use host's address